# Set my phone contacts to sync to Google not Google to phone

Tags: contacts, samsung-galaxy-s-2, sync, google

I want to set my phone to pull contacts from my Google Contacts so that it uses google as a master.

I organised my contacts on Google Contacts page and when I synced my phone it messed everything up again because instead of pulling down from Google it uploaded everything from the phone. :(

I am using Samsung Galaxy S2 with CM9

Comment: When you're done organizing them on the Google Contacts page, and before syncing with your phone, go to Applications->Manage Applications and clear data+cache of the contacts app (plus some other service I cannot recall currently, something like a contacts provider if there is). Then open your contacts app to verify no contact is left. That done, sync again -- as there are no contacts on your device, it should simply download the data from the Google server.

Comment: @Izzy - recommend you post above comment as an answer.

Comment: @Sparx OK, done :)

Comment: Just FYI, it doesn't sync with *either* as a master - it performs a merge.

Comment: On GMail's website there should somewhere be an option to roll back an older snapshot of your contacts, just before it's been messed up.

Answer (score 1):

When you're done organizing your contacts on the Google Contacts page, and *before* syncing with your phone, go to Applications->Manage Applications and clear data+cache of the contacts app (plus some other service I cannot recall currently, something like a contacts provider if there is). Then open your contacts app to verify no contact is left.

That done, sync again -- as there are no contacts on your device, it cannot upload anything (and thus not mess things up again), but should simply download the data from the Google server.